# Cumulative sum with group by and join

Tags: t-sql

I'm a little struggled with finding a clean way to do this. Assume that I have the following records in my table named `Records`:

```
   |Name|  |InsertDate|  |Size|
    john    30.06.2015     1
    john    10.01.2016     10
    john    12.01.2016     100
    john    05.03.2016     1000
    doe     01.01.2016     1
```

How do I get the records for year of 2016 and month is equal to or less than 3 grouped by month(even that month does not exists e.g. month 2 in this case) with cumulative sum of `Size` including that month? I want to get the result as the following:

```
   |Name|  |Month|  |Size|
    john      1      111
    john      2      111
    john      3      1111
    doe       1      1
```

Comment: You need a calendar table which you can use for the outer-join. See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) or [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3).

Comment: Actually I wanted to supply some static values (for months) as left outer join table but couldn't find a way for it..

Comment: What static values? Also note that your query should work if your customer asks you for the last 2 years, so you need to make it dynamic and include the year. It's not so difficult once you have a calendar table. You just need to group by year+month and get the start+end dates by sub-queries selecting `MIN(InsertDate)` and  `MAX(InsertDate)`.

Comment: What I need is for only that year. I mean group by should be only for that year's months but cumulative can be for the last 10 years, I can make it static with no problem (for cumulative count). What I meant by static values is like a temporary table supplied with calendar values to be able to use it with left outer join but I don't want to create that kind of table because of lots of company rules etc :).  I don't know if it makes any sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have already stated, you simply need a table with dates in that you can `join` *from* to give you the dates that your source table does not have records for:

```
-- Build the source data table.
declare @t table(Name nvarchar(10)
                ,InsertDate date
                ,Size int
                );
insert into @t values
 ('john','20150630',1   )
,('john','20160110',10  )
,('john','20160112',100 )
,('john','20160305',1000)
,('doe' ,'20160101',1   );

-- Specify the year you want to search for by storing the first day here.
declare @year date = '20160101';

-- This derived table builds a set of dates that you can join from.
-- LEFT JOINing from here is what gives you rows for months without records in your source data.
with Dates
as
(
    select @year as MonthStart
            ,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,@year)) as MonthEnd
    union all
    select dateadd(month,1,MonthStart)
            ,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,2,MonthStart))
    from Dates
    where dateadd(month,1,MonthStart) < dateadd(yyyy,1,@year)
)
select t.Name
        ,d.MonthStart
        ,sum(t.Size) as Size
from Dates d
    left join @t t
        on(t.InsertDate <= d.MonthEnd)
where d.MonthStart <= '20160301'        -- Without knowing what your logic is for specifying values only up to March, I have left this part for you to automate.
group by t.Name
        ,d.MonthStart
order by t.Name
        ,d.MonthStart;
```

If you have a static date reference table in your database, you don't need to do the derived table creation and can just do:

```
select d.DateValue
      ,<Other columns>
from DatesReferenceTable d
    left join <Other Tables> o
        on(d.DateValue = o.AnyDateColumn)
etc
```

Comment: You forgot to include the GROUP BY at the end:
GROUP BY t.name, d.MonthStart

Comment: Doh!!!! My bad. The scroll bar was not showing up for the code block on my phone. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up using something else because of some company rules (e.g. queries must start with 'select' clause etc. and that 'with' clause was not possible for me to use, silly I know but our DBAs won't approve that..)This'll work for most of the users though..

Comment: @sotn Are you able to create a table of dates to reference?  The `with cte` is only required to create such a table and can therefore be ignored if you do.  Having a dates table available is also incredibly useful in general.

Comment: I got your point but our company rules are so strict and have tons of rules about querying prod db (I work in a bank btw if you wondered why it is so strict:) ). I had to use a query starting with `SELECT`, no `cte` and even no `declare` keywords before or after that `SELECT` etc. So what I did was using group by `DATEPART(MONTH, InsertDate)` without left join (unfortunately..) but it solved my problem. It wasn't perfect and complete but did the job fortunately :) Thanks again..

Comment: @sotn  That is what I am suggesting. Speak with your DBAs about whether or not you could get a static Date reference table added to your database.  It would mean you can do queries like the one I suggested above without the need for the `cte`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that utilizes a tally table (aka numbers table) to create the date table. Note my comments.

```
-- Build the source data table.
declare @t table(Name nvarchar(10), InsertDate date, Size int);
insert into @t values
 ('john','20150630',1   )
,('john','20160110',10  )
,('john','20160112',100 )
,('john','20160305',1000)
,('doe' ,'20160101',1   );

-- A year is fine, don't need a date data type
declare @year smallint = 2016;

WITH -- dummy rows for a tally table:
E AS (SELECT E FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(e)),
dateRange(totalDays, mn, mx) AS -- Get the range and number of months to create
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(InsertDate), MAX(InsertDate)), MIN(InsertDate), MAX(InsertDate)
  FROM @t
),
iTally(N) AS -- Tally Oh! Create an inline Tally (aka numbers) table starting with 0
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1
  FROM E a CROSS JOIN E b CROSS JOIN E c CROSS JOIN E d
),
RunningTotal AS -- perform a running total by year/month for each person (Name)
(
  SELECT
    yr = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, n, mn)),
    mo = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, n, mn)),
    Name, 
    Size = SUM(Size) OVER 
      (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, n, mn)), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, n, mn)))
  FROM iTally
  CROSS JOIN dateRange
  LEFT JOIN @t ON MONTH(InsertDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, n, mn))
  WHERE N <= totalDays
) -- Final output will only return rows where the year matches @year:
SELECT
  name = ISNULL(name, LAG(Name, 1) OVER (ORDER BY yr, mo)),
  yr, mo,
  size = ISNULL(Size, LAG(Size, 1) OVER (ORDER BY yr, mo))
FROM RunningTotal
WHERE yr = @year
GROUP BY yr, mo, name, size;
```

Results:

```
name       yr          mo          size
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
doe        2016        1           1
john       2016        1           111
john       2016        2           111
john       2016        3           1111
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice usage of tally tables.

Comment: Be aware that using functions like `month` and `year` in your `join`s and `partition`s prevents the use of indexes as each join value needs to be calculated.

Comment: @iamdave - That's why I it's good to have tables designed at the correct grain. If you're joining or grouping by month and year there should be a month and year column, AND it should be indexed correctly.